# Understanding CSS Float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am leanring HTML and CSS. I have been muddled up by `float` property. I don't why this is confusing me a lot. I am using these [articles](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/) [to](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/) [understand](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm). I got this part when we apply `float` element is put out of the normal flow and floated to left and right of it's parent based on the value of `float` and the content below it will flow around it and try to wrap it.
The part where I am confused is I'll explain by example. I have three div A, B, C. As I have shared in the snippet:

```css
body {
  background: #eaeaed;
}
div{
  border : 2px solid #ff00ff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.divA{
  background: yellow;
}
.divB{
  background: green;
}
.divC{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="divA">
  <span>Div A</span>
</div>
<div class="divB">
  <span>Div B</span>
</div>
<div class="divC">
  <span>Div C</span>
</div>
```

Now when I apply `float:left` to `divA`. It gets moved out of the flow and `divB` takes it's position. But I am not able to understand what is happening with the text inside divB. Why the text of B and C are collapsing/overlapping. I mean when A is floated, it should be moved out of the flow and the element below should take it's place but don't know why only `divB` is taking it's place but B's content is stil there as it is. Thanks for you help.

```css
body {
  background: #eaeaed;
}
div{
  border : 2px solid #ff00ff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.divA{
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
.divB{
  background: green;
}
.divC{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="divA">
  <span>Div A</span>
</div>
<div class="divB">
  <span>Div B</span>
</div>
<div class="divC">
  <span>Div C</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The box of B moves underneath A's original position, but the text does not. The text has to wrap around the float instead, since the main idea of floats is for text to wrap around rather than be overlapped by the floating content.

The word "wrap" implies that the text should appear next to A rather than underneath it, but the width of the two elements is the same leaving no room for the text to appear side by side with A. Increasing the width of B shows that the text does start off side by side when there is room for it to do so:

```css
body {
  background: #eaeaed;
}
div{
  border : 2px solid #ff00ff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.divA{
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
.divB{
  width: 160px;
  background: green;
}
.divC{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="divA">
  <span>Div A</span>
</div>
<div class="divB">
  <span>Div B</span>
</div>
<div class="divC">
  <span>Div C</span>
</div>
```

The B text appears to be overlapping with the C text because, strictly speaking, the B text is *overflowing* the box as a consequence of floating A. Content that's overflowing a box — even if that box has `overflow: visible`, as is the case for all three elements here — has no effect on content outside the box.

Comment: So, the floating Box A is acting as content of Box B here?

Comment: @Mr_Green: No, A is taken out of the flow and B is laid out as though A was never there. Since both elements have the same dimensions it just gives the appearance of one box "containing" the other. And as the question has established, the text behaves differently.

Comment: @BoltClock I am not able to understand: "wrap" implies that the text should appear next to A rather than underneath it. When I set `float:right` of A, A goes to right but B and it's content remains in the left as it is. Can you please help me to understand what is happening here. Here's the pen https://codepen.io/programmerhk/pen/wzkoYE?editors=1100

Answer (score 3):

See [Visual formatting model - Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

So `.divA` overlaps `.divB`. But the line boxes in `.divB` shrink.

It's easier to see if you let `.divB` be wider than the float:

```css
body {
  background: #eaeaed;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid #ff00ff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.divA {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}
.divB {
  background: green;
}
.divC {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="divA">
  <span>Div A</span>
</div>
<div class="divB">
  <span>Div B</span>
</div>
<div class="divC">
  <span>Div C</span>
</div>
```

However, in your case `.divB` has the same width as `.divA`. So the line box shrinks to 0. Therefore, `.divB`'s text does not fit there, and wraps to the next line box. That line box will overflow `.divB` and overlap `.divC` because you used equal `line-height` and `height`.