# Unexpected behavior using float: left

Tags: html, css, css-float

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: green;"></div>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: yellow;">Hello World!</div>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: blue;"></div>
```

In the above example, I don't understand a few things:

1. Why is the green div is stacked on top of the yellow div?
2. Why is the text `"Hello World"` printed where the blue div is, and not where the yellow div is?

I understand `float: left;` to push that element to the left and have all the following elements to render as if nothing happened, while still acknowledging the space taken by the floated element.

So I expected this:

1. Yellow div on the right side of the green div.
2. Blue div right below the green div.
3. The text `"Hello World"` printed on the yellow div.

Comment: you missed one key point :  Elements after a floating element will flow around it

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264773/understanding-css-float, but I can't come up with a good title for either question.

Comment: @bhv: That statement is as vague as it gets. Define "Elements [...] will flow".

Answer (score 0):

Only content is wrapping around the floating elements, other (non-inline) elements do not...

As your yellow `<div>` is a block element, it would not "wrap around" your floated element.

Add `display: inline-block;` to your yellow element, as shown below:

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: green;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: yellow;">Hello World!</div>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: blue;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `p` tag is also a block element but floats around. (https://jsfiddle.net/41kdv7zL/)

Comment: Nope, it is not floating around, it just bigger, as you do not specified its size...

Comment: By the way, only content is wrapping around the floating elements, other (non-inline) elements do not...

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto: Your "by the way" is what your answer should have been in the first place. Your answer as it is doesn't tell anyone anything. No wonder Novice wasn't convinced.