# floating elements are outside of containing blocks?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML/CSS, just some questions on floating elements, below is the code

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left; 
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device_width,initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Page Title</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="makeup.css">
</head>
<body>


<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left_second">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

so my questions are:

1. It is said that ***floating element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow (in contrast to absolute positioning).*** But what does "still remaining a part of the flow" actually mean? As we can see that second div overlaps the first div, which means that the first div is not part of flow anymore? the only thing can make it "still remaining a part of the flow" is to set the `float:left` on the second div, then the second is on the right of the first div, which seems like the first div does exist in the flow, is my understanding correct?
2. Why the thrid div is outside of the containing block? why it is not inside the containing block just like first and second divs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding CSS Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264773/understanding-css-float)

Answer (score 3):

It remains a part of the flow because text still wrap around float thus they are still considered a part of the flow unlike `position:absolute` elements that will no more affect the flow.

> The float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, **allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it**. The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow (in contrast to absolute positioning).<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)</sup>

---

To answer your question, let's add the properties step by step.

Intitially we have this:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  /*float: left;*/ 
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  /*float: right;*/
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left_second">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</section>
```

No float element, each div taking a row and all of them inside the border of the section. Let's float the first one and make the blue background a bit transparent and remove the last div.

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
}

.right {
  /*float: right;*/
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left_second">2</div>
  <!--<div class="right">3</div>-->
</section>
```

As you can see the blue div is completely overlapping the float element and the text of the blue div is outside. Here you facing an oveflow issue. Let's increase the width of the blue box to better see:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
}

.right {
  /*float: right;*/
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left_second">2</div>
  <!--<div class="right">3</div>-->
</section>
```

As you can see, the text (`2`) start after the float element and don't overlap it because  text wrap around float element unlike block element. In other words, the blue div will start on the top of the float element but not its content and if the size is reduced the text will get pushed to the next line and will overflow:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
  transition:1s;
}
.left_second:hover {
  width:200px;
}

.right {
  /*float: right;*/
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left_second">2 (hover me)</div>
  <!--<div class="right">3</div>-->
</section>
```

You may also notice that **only** the blue div is surrounded by the blue border of the section because its the only non floated element and since it overlap the pink this one will necessarly be there too. If you remove the blue div you see that the pink one is outside:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
  transition:1s;
}
.left_second:hover {
  width:200px;
}

.right {
  /*float: right;*/
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <!--<div class="left_second">2</div> -->
  <!--<div class="right">3</div>-->
</section>
```

Now if we re-add the third div it will start at the bottom of the blue div and inside the section:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
}

.right {
  /*float: right;*/
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left_second">2</div> 
  <div class="right">3</div>
</section>
```

And if you float it to the right, it will be place on the right and outside the section:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left_second">2</div> 
  <div class="right">3</div>
</section>
```

That's why we need to clear float to avoid the overlap effect and the *outside* effect:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow:hidden; /*make the float inside*/
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  clear:left; /*clear left float*/
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left_second">2</div> 
  <div class="right">3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Very good answer @Temani Afif, but I have a SUPER DOUBT , so how does this rule apply on floated elements, or that rule doesn't apply anymore? `'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block ` HERE: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth thanks in advace

Comment: can we say that NOW IT IS TRANSLATED TO "the sum of all the floated elements (the floating box itself) must be equal to the width of the containing block"? @Temani Afif

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer that rule doesn't apply, there is a section for floated element in that same doc you need to consider

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer then there is this section: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats (at the end) that gives all the float rules and how they should align with each other

Comment: excellent, @Temani Afif, one last question derived from this comment. for flexbox and grid layout would you also not apply the rule of "margin-left + border-left-width.... = width of containing block"? +1 i.e. in flexbox and grid layout does it not apply either?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer no, flexbox has its own algorithm that has nothing to do with the CSS 2 Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#layout-algorithm .. same for CSS grid: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/

Comment: thank you very much @Temani Afif you have solved a doubt I had since I started in flexbox, grid layout and floats? + 1 and marked as useful answer. I needed the wisdom of an OUTSTANDING reference in CSS as you are.

Comment: Hi, @Temani Afif I have seen the answer and the comments and a doubt has arisen in my mind, does Out of Flow ONLY mean that it changes the "painting order" of the elements or Out of Flow means that a "new layer" (as absolute position) is "added" on top of the HTML (of the web page)? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Daniel out of the flow means that we don't really care about what elements come next or before. it will get placed on the screen based on the position you will define regardless of everything else

Comment: thank you very much, @Temani Afif, flexbox and grid layout ARE IN THE FLOW but NOT in the normal flow, correct?

Comment: @Daniel we cannot say yes or no. Flexbox/ Grid are layout algorithm, they are abstract concept. We consider elements when saying "out of the flow" or not. We say Element X is out of the flow or not (based on the properties applied to it)

Comment: great @Temani Afif "We say Element X is out of the flow or not (based on the properties applied to it" -  these PROPERTIES ARE LIMITED to `position: absolute | fixed` OR if the element is `float: left | right`, right?

Comment: @Daniel as far as I know yes but we can have more properties (less known or that will be added in the future)

Comment: Thank you very much @Temani Afif, you helped me A LOT, +1 and marked as a USEFUL answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the 2nd div to `position: relative;`, as `div`s are block-level elements, it breaks to a new line. Therefore, when you then set the 3rd element to `float: right;`, it is floated in line with the second div, not the first one (on the line below). You can understand this easier by just removing the second `div`:

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  float: left; 
  background: pink;
}

.left_second {
  position:relative;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device_width,initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Page Title</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="makeup.css">
</head>
<body>


<section>
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <!-- <div class="left_second">2</div> -->
  <div class="right">3</div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```